# How to set up an adjacent matrix with a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to simulate a network model. In that, n.people=100. I want to assign half of the cells as [index of people,1] (which is the roommate connection) and half of the cell as [index of people, 3](which is the coworker connection).

```
g <- graph.formula(1-2, 1-3,2-3,2-4)
distribution <- matrix(NA,n.people,n.people)

#Set up the roommate connection
for (i in seq(1,n.people,by=3)){
  distribution[i,] <-3
}

#Set up the coworker connection
for (i in seq(1,n.people,by=1)){
  for(j in 1:n.people){
    distribution[i,j] <-1
  }
}
```

I am aware that this is not the correct way to do this, but I am quite new to R and do not know how to fix it. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by half? Do you mean the upper and lower triangular sub-matrices? Can you give a small example? a 3x3 adjacent matrix?

Comment: hey, I meant that I want to assign random 50 percent of the matrix ( in the case of 3*3 matrix, maybe 4 or 5 people with a coworker, which is indicated by rows=1]